# HLS with different audio and video quality

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, exoplayer

I am trying to implement a adaptive streaming having 3 video qualities and one audio quality. The Vision is when the bandwidth decreases switch to audio only.but for some reason only audio only file is being played. its not switching to any other quality. I am using exoplayer at client side.

Here is the content of master m3u8 file.

```
#EXTM3U
 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=64000
 audio/output.m3u8
 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1500000
 low/output.m3u8
 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2400000
 medium/output.m3u8
 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=4400000
 high/output.m3u8
```

Please help and advise, Thanks in advance

Comment: which programming language you are using

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps players just choose the first stream. Try changing the order of the variants. Try adding other parameters, such as RESOLUTION and CODECS.

Update: Although it may not apply to other players, [HLS Authoring Specification for Apple Devices](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/http_live_streaming_hls_authoring_specification_for_apple_devices) says:

> 9. Multivariant Playlist requirements
>
> 9.1. Your EXT-X-STREAM-INF tag MUST always provide the CODECS attribute.
>
> 9.2. Your EXT-X-STREAM-INF tag MUST always provide the RESOLUTION attribute if the rendition includes video.
>
> 9.14. You MUST include the AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH attribute.

Perhaps the player opens the first Variant Stream, then guessing from (because there are no CODEC attributes) that it assumes all Variants Streams have only audio.

Comment: Tried, But the same behaviour. And i strongly feel order of the stream has no impact on the stream selection , Please correct if i am wrong ?

Comment: It's true that [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8216) says "Algorithms used by the client to switch between Variant Streams are beyond the scope of this document." Have you tried adding the CODECS attribute?

Comment: Also, have you tried with other players? Maybe it's a limitation, or a bug, of the player you were using.